# How to solve this problem , in package body

Tags: jenkins

Scanning processes...
Scanning linux images...

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

No services Need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaires on This host.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This output comes from the invoked program needrestart and is just an information, as "No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host" basically translates to "All is up to date".

The check that returns "Failed to check for processor microcode upgrades" can not check the microcode of your CPU. It can be skipped by creating a new conf-file in /etc/needrestart/conf.d/ with the content $nrconf{ucodehints} = 0;

If you want to get rid of the messages altogether then you can uninstall the package needrestart. But then processes will not be restarted automatically after their dependecies have been updated.